# Need to get a series of values of dependent variable based on a particular level in one of the independent variables in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

The general ways of Extracting a column value based on another column in Pandas were not working in my case.
I am having a data frame with two variables, `Salary` and `EducationLevels`. Salary is having continuous values while EducationLevels has four categories namely `'A', 'B', 'C',` and `'D'`. I need to get Salary values for EducxationLevel `'A'`. The below code is not working:

```
df['Salary'][df['EducationLevels']=="A]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df["EducationLevels"] == "A"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['Salary'][df['EducationLevels']=="A"]`

Change this into

`df[df['EducationLevels']=="A"]['Salary']`.

Another way to filter data is using `df.query`. For instance, df.query("EducationLevels == 'A'").Salary will do as well.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestions. But i got the answer. I  included a SPACE before 'A' and it worked. So the final code that worked for me is:                                                          
                    df['Salary'][df['EducationLevels']==" A"]